# PHP session slow online worked great on local

Tags: php, session

HI after searching the entire web and gaining a lot of grey hairs, I feel that I have to ask here. 
i'm having a problem with my PHP session login at my website. When logging in, it should redirect to the user profile, it does (sometimes), sometimes I have to refresh before it happens. The same issue occurs when I browse the pages of the website, it suddenly seems to be logged out, until i refresh (maybe several refreshes until it seems to be logged in again).
And when logging out, it does it, but when browsing the site, it's suddenly logged in again. 
All this works like a charm at local with MAMP, but does all this on my server.

Does anyone have some kind of wild guess on why this could be?

My website is build with an index file with a switch statement, which points to a function that uses require to load the needed templates to be shown. So basically the user never leaves the index. The index starts with session_start();
and when the user logs in the session values are declared:

```
    $_SESSION['userName'] = $userName;
      $_SESSION['uId'] = $resultsusername['User']->uId;
      $_SESSION['login'] = 'loggedin';

      header( "Location: index.php?action=viewProfile" );
```

and here is the logout:

```
    function userLogout() {
unset( $_SESSION['userName'] );
unset( $_SESSION['uId'] );
unset( $_SESSION['login'] );
session_destroy();
header( "Location: index.php" );
}
```

And to show how the index works, heres some of the switch:

```
    switch ( $action ) {
case 'userLogin':
userLogin();
break;
case 'userLogout':
userLogout();
break;
```

All urls are index.php/action=logout

Comment: Might not be a solution to your problem, but put `exit()` after `header('location...');` to stop script execution.

Comment: Instead of using multiple sessions per users you could better give a single object with all the variables to a single session.

Comment: Thanks will look into putting them together in one session :) - the exit() didn't seem to solve it. might be better, but the performance of it, seems a bit random. 
the session_start(); is located at the top of the index page, which then is on top of all pages, that's correct, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is some problem with write performance at hoster's server (maybe they oversell and server is under very high load).
Try your script somewhere else.

Comment: That kinda would make sense, because of the quick response of it on local. Might be able to put it on another, will try that! :)

Comment: Stupid host! it fixed it to move it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
 // this starts the session 
 session_start(); 

 // this sets variables in the session 
 $_SESSION['test']='testing'; 

 print "Done"; 
 ?>
```

Use session_start() and while logout use session_detroy()